# Position of subscript

Tags: math-mode

I am doing the following:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation*}
\top_{i}
\end{equation*}
\end{document}
```

and obtain

[image]

which I do not find very nice because the subscript is very far to the right. Is there a way to make this nicer?

The same problem does not occur if I do, e.g., `T_{i}` instead.

Is `\top` an exception? Are there any other symbols causing the problem? And can we do something about it that is global or should we do local adjustments only?

Comment: `\top_{\!i}`? or maybe `\top_{\!i\,}`? Or are you looking for some kind of automated solution?

Comment: @campa Thanks for suggesting the corrections. Yes, I would have liked something more automatic.

Comment: (Fishing from memory, hence only comment) The automatic horizontal shift works only with some characters (I believe the `letters`, i.e. family 1, but I'm not entirely sure).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not an “exception”. There is no kerning information for `\top` that allows for automatic kerning of a subscript.

You can add it, though. Use a more meaningful name than `\mytop`.

```latex
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{mathtools,xparse}

\NewDocumentCommand{\mytop}{e{^_}}{%
  \top
  \IfValueT{#1}{^{#1}}%
  \IfValueT{#2}{_{\!#2}}%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
\mytop_{i}+\mytop+\mytop^{a}+\mytop_{i}^{a}
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Would `\RenewDocumentCommand{\top}{e{^_}}{\mathchar"23E ... }` be very evil? `;-)`

Comment: To me \mytop_{i}^{a} is not nice.

Comment: @campa Yes, it would. I’d prefer saving `\top` and redefining.

Comment: @egreg Quite nice and exactly what I was looking for..

Answer (score 1):

To have something more "automated", I just can think in make a macro to do this. Something like:

```
\newcommand\sbr[2]{%
        {#1}_{\!#2\,}}
```

then, in text, you use `\sbr{\top}{i}`. Or, if you will always use `\top`:

```
\newcommand\sbr[1]{%
        {\top}_{\!#1\,}}
```

and use will be `\sbr{i}`.

Comment: Will sure work. In fact my question was maybe wrongly targeted to all these symbols, including [ \top` that may cause a similar problem. Modifioed the question to be more accurate. Thanks anyway.